# Is it possible to supress Jenkins plugin deprecation warnings? If yes, how?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

A few months ago Nexus Platform Plugin [distribution has been suspended](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nexus-jenkins-plugin/) due to [usage of a priopietary dependency](https://github.com/jenkins-infra/helpdesk/issues/3742) which made Jenkins show the plugin as obsolete.
[image]

I've looked around but I can't see any way to supress this message. I can supress warnings about vulnerabilities which I can't deal with at the moment but surely I need this plugin and I can't remove it so I want this notification off so I can only see things I can deal with.